# Apply Rails controller filter to all controllers of a particular namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, filter, controllers

I have a bunch of controllers in a namespace `Foo`.
I'd like to apply a `before_filter 'require_user'` to all of them, but not to other controllers, that do not belong to `Foo` namespace.

Is there any way to accomplish this besides explicitly invoking a before_filter method in each controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a `FooController` class which includes the `before_filter` and then use that as the base class for all controllers in that namespace.

Comment: How can you do that? I tried creating the Class, but it does't inherit the before filter

Comment: something like: `class Namespace::ResourceController < Namespace::BaseController`

Comment: or for a more realistic example: `class Admin::InviteTokensController < Admin::AdminController`

Answer (score 1):

No. Not other than doing some really nasty `ObjectSpace` kind of hacks.